# Detect beyond compare version installed

Tags: batch-file, wmic, beyondcompare

Is there a way to detect the beyond compare version installed on windows machine from a command line ?

I tried using wmic but it doesn't seems to work

```
wmic product where "name like 'Beyond%%'"
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare version can be found in the registry:

Beyond Compare 4:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare 4\Version
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare 4\Version
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare\Version
```

Beyond Compare 3:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare 3\Version
```

Beyond Compare 2:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare\Version
```

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded and made a test with a batch file.
I have Windows 10 (32 bits) so the folder installation in my case is located as :
`%ProgramFiles%\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe`.

So you should change it on this script if it isn't located there !

---

Just copy and paste this code into your notepad and save it as :
***Get_File_Version.bat***

```bat
@echo off & color 0B
Title Get Version of any application using WMIC
Set "AppPath=%ProgramFiles%\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe"
echo( & echo( Getting Version of "%AppPath%"
Call :GetVersion "%AppPath%" Version
cls
echo( & echo( %AppPath% : v%Version%
Pause
Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetVersion <App> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
Set "App=%~1"
Set "App=%App:\=\\%"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
    'wmic datafile where "name='%App%%'" get version /Value 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

***EDIT :***
Based on answer from @Chris Kennedy that give me an idea to query the registry in order to extract Executable Path and its version too.

---

```bat
@echo off & color 0B
Title Get ExePath and Version From Registry using Reg Query

@for /f "tokens=3* skip=2 delims= " %%a in (
    'Reg Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare" /v ExePath'
) do (
    set "ExePath=%%a%%b"
)

@for /f "tokens=3 skip=2 delims= " %%a in (
    'Reg Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare" /v Version'
) do (
    set "Version=%%a"
)

echo( ExePath = "%ExePath%"
echo( Version = v%Version%
Pause & Exit
```